# How to send only the admin a push notification when a collection gets a doc added to it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter application that allows users to book appointments and those get stored in the bookings collection, now I have an admin that listens to the stream of bookings and gets a listview updated each time a new one is added, now I have made fcm token for each user storing it as a field in the users collection, I am trying to implement a cloud function I am successfully getting the fcm token but the following error occurs:

> sendBookingNotification: Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response: "

This is my index.js in my functions folder in my flutter project:

```
/**
 * Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
 *
 * const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
 * const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
 *
 * See a full list of supported triggers at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
 */

const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

// exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
//   logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendBookingNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("bookings/{bookingId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        // Get the newly added booking data
        const bookingData = snapshot.data();

        // Retrieve the admin's FCM token from Firestore
        const adminFCMToken = await getAdminFCMToken(); // Implement the function to get admin's FCM token

        if (adminFCMToken) {
            // Send a notification to the admin
            const message = {
                data: {
                    title: "New Booking",
                    body: `A new booking has been added: ${bookingData.serviceTitle}`,
                },
                token: adminFCMToken,
            };

            try {
                await admin.messaging().send(message);
                console.log("Notification sent successfully.");
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error sending notification:", error);
            }
        }
    });

// Function to get the admin's FCM token from Firestore
async function getAdminFCMToken() {
    try {
        const adminDoc = await admin.firestore().collection("users").where("user type", "==", "admin").get();

        if (!adminDoc.empty) {
            // Assuming there's only one admin, so we retrieve the first document found
            const adminData = adminDoc.docs[0].data();
            console.log("Admin Data:", adminData);


            // Check if the admin document has an "fcmtoken" field
            if (adminData.fcmtoken) { // Update field name here
                return adminData.fcmtoken; // Update field name here
            } else {
                console.error("Admin document does not have an FCM token.");
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            console.error("No admin found in Firestore.");
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching admin FCM token:", error);
        return null;
    }
}
```